# moviepy.editory.VideoFileClip - RGB or BGR?

Tags: python, opencv, moviepy

I'm loading video using VideoFileClip and wondering if it loads video using RGB or BGR palette?

```
clip = VideoFileClip(myVideo.mp4')
```

I ask because I want to convert image to grayscale and don't know if I should use

```
return cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

or

```
return cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is an educated assumption**

If you look at the rest of the framework everything is in RGB not BGR, so it is likely you are going to need to use RGB

https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/videoclips.html?highlight=rgb

That page doesn't specifically talk about RGB for VideoClip but it does for fileclip etc